# Shipping methods are not displayed accordingly in Magento 1.8

Tags: sorting, magento

How can I display the list of my shipping methods according to the order numbers that I have set in their input fields of **Sort Order**?

I have set each shipping method's **Sort Order** in my backoffice, but they are not displayed accordingly.

For instance, in my backoffice, I have these shipping methods,

```
Method Name: bestway
Sort Order: 1

Method Name: Free
Sort Order: 2

Method Name: Chronopost
Sort Order: 3
```

But they are not displayed in this order in `frontend\argenties\default\template\checkout/cart/shipping.phtml`

```
    <?php
    $methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();
    $shipping = array();
    foreach($methods as $_ccode => $_carrier):
        if($_methods = $_carrier->getAllowedMethods()):
            if(!$_title = Mage::getStoreConfig("carriers/$_ccode/title"))
                $_title = $_ccode;

            foreach($_methods as $_mcode => $_method):
                $_code = $_ccode . '_' . $_mcode;
                $shipping[$_code] = array('title' => $_method,'carrier' => $_title);
            ?>

            <li><input type="radio" name="estimate_method" value="<?php echo $_code;?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_code ?>"<?php if($_code === $this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?>> <span class="item-text-shipping-method"><?php echo $_title;?></span></li>

            <?php endforeach;?>

        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

Result,

```
Method Name: Free
Method Name: bestway
Method Name: Chronopost
```

`Method Name: bestway` should be on the top in the list, but it is always dropped to the second. Why? Any idea how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware of the following facts:

1. Custom Shipping Methods (also known as offline shipping) will always display before the Real-Time Shipping methods.
2. Shipping methods within each carrier will display in order of price (lowest to highest.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates):?>
        <?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
            <li>
                    <input name="estimate_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getCode()) ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio" />
                    <span class="item-text-shipping-method">
                        <?php echo $this->getCarrierName($code);?>
                    </span>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Try this code, i alerted this code form base/default/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml file

Comment: the shipping methods are not able to be displayed sometimes with this code. I have to reload it only then I can see them.

Answer (score 0):

The shipping methods are sorted based upon price, and when they are all the same price, it doesn't look at other fields determine which one should come first.

I had a similar issue, where I had my delivery methods on one set price, so I added additional sorting criteria to `Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Results.php` file particularly the `sortRatesByPrice()` function.

If you want to make changes to core files, be sure to copy them to your local pool.